# Bitrix news:list сортировка

Tags: битрикс

К одному сайту подключено большое количество региональных поддоменов.
В настройках инфоблока заведено свойство `REGION`, по которому необходимо сортировать элементы в многочисленных компонентах на страницах сайта.

К примеру, на поддомене *arh.example.com* отображен список последних статей за месяц, но приоритетными в списке показываются статьи по региону Архангельск (REGION=3), затем по дате активности убыванию.

Требуется настроить сортировку, чтобы к запросу добавлялось `ORDER BY FIELD(PROPERTY_REGION_VALUE, 3) DESC`, где *3* - id текущего региона.

Пробую кастомизировать компонент *news.list*, в котором вызывается метод `CIBlockElement::getList()`, но, судя по всему, он не позволяет осуществлять сортировку таким образом. Есть ли способ правильно и без костылей добавить нужное условие в запрос, не переписывая при этом половину методов битрикса?

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, свойство REGION у вас числовое. Прочитайте [здесь](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=3796&LESSON_PATH=3913.4776.4620.3796), если еще не читали. Насколько я понял, не должно быть никаких проблем с сортировкой по вашему свойству согласно этой статье. А если проблемы есть, то в чем они проявляются?

Comment: Неочевидно, как вывести сначала новые статьи с регионом с id 3, затем по всем остальным регионам. Как сделать это на уровне SQL-запроса, я знаю, а какое условие указывать в ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD -- нет.

Answer (score 0):

CIBlockElement::getList() такой вариант сортировки не поддерживает (не может сгенерировать такой тип SQL запроса).

Самое тривиальное решение: Использовать 2 компонета - в первом вы используете фильтр - выводить только данные по третьему региону.
Во втором - наоборот, его исключаете.
Но вероятнее всего вам такой вариант не подойдет, плюс будут проблемы с постраничной навигацией.

Логичнее использовать такое решение:
Написать обработчик события на сохранение/изменение элементов ИБ. В случае если Статья региона 3 (Архангельск) то изменяем сортировку на большее число.
(по-умолчанию сортировка 500 обычно, можно поставить 700)
В самом же компоненте настроить сортировку:
Первую - по дате, на уменьшение
Вторичную - по сортировке, на уменьшение

Но если вам нужно это для каждого поддомена региона, это решение подойдет только если вы выводите Статьи по текущему региону + некие общие Статьи.
(что кстати лучше для индексации, чем если вы выводите абсолютно одни и те же Статьи на всех поддоменах но в разной сортировке)

Если же второй вариант не подходит (по предполагаемой выше причине),
можно заморочиться с result_modifier.php 
Т.е. перед выводом вы пересортировываете Статьи в нужном вам порядке, конечно же будет стоять проблема по разбивке на страницы, но так же решаемая. Но в это уже не углубляюсь, т.к. не известно нужно ли оно для данного решения.

P.S. как видите очень много предположений о вашей ситуации, т.к. не достаточно раскрыта ситуация в вашем вашем вопросе.

Comment: Во всех региональных поддоменах (их 98 штук) отображается один и тот же сайт с одними и теми же компонентами, в которых настроен вывод, к примеру, последних за месяц, статей. Вопрос в том, как отсортировать эти самые статьи сначала по привязке к текущему региону, затем по дате по убыванию, добавив в запрос `order by field(название_поля, 3) desc`. Сейчас временно скопировал компонент `news.list` и класс `CIBlockElement` с формированием запроса и захардкодил такую сортировку, но ведь должно же быть человеческое решение.